# Installing Rails on Ubuntu behind the proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I am under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I am behind the proxy.
I have installed rvm to manage ruby versions.
I would like to install the rails but I have encountered the problem:

```
test@U205-UBUNTU:~$ gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Forbidden 403 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I have tried different ways to force gem to use proxy setting:

```
1. gem install rails --http-proxy=http://10.10.16.8:3128  

2. gem install rails -p=http://10.10.16.8:3128  

3. export http_proxy=http://10.10.16.8:3128  

4. I have added to .bashrc lines:   
export http_proxy=http://10.10.16.8:3128  
export https_proxy=https://10.10.16.8:3128  

5. I have added to /etc/environment lines:   
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"  
http_proxy=http://10.10.16.8:3128  
https_proxy=https://10.10.16.8:3128
```

**But nothing helped me.

I am still getting the message:**

```
test@U205-UBUNTU:~$ gem install rails
    ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
        bad response Forbidden 403 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

But **apt-get** and **rvm** work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem with my proxy settings that restrict an access to Internet.
Sorry for incorrect question). The solution here is to add (as a superuser) the following to the file `/etc/environment`:

```
http_proxy=http://<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>
```

where

- `<proxy-host>` is the real name of your proxy machine (or the ip address)
- `<proxy-port>` is the port number you have to use

You don't have to set the proxy then for Gem.